# How to look up the explanation of keyword in Coq Software Foundations?

Tags: coq

Coq has excellent set of guides called Software Foundations whose index can be found: https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/coqindex.html

I am trying to decipher the Coq code:

```
Parameter A: Type.
Variable T: Type.
```

And I would like to get documenation or examples from the Software Foundations where those keywords are defined, explained and where the examples are provided. How can I look up relevant Software Foundations chapter? Is there index for keywords? I am aware of Gallina language specification but it is specification of  grammar and not the meaning of the keywords.

I would really like to know what `Parameter` and what `Variable` mean in Coq?

Comment: Have you considered referring to the Coq documentation? That would be the most authoritative and up-to-date source about Coq proper. For example: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/coq-cmdindex.html

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the material I was looking for!

Comment: @RobBlanco, please make this a proper answer, so that we can up-vote it!